# 'ping' is not recognized as an internal command or external, an operable program or a batch file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ping

I have a simple script in Python using VS Code to make a ping verification, I don't know why it isn't recognize 'ping' as a command.

```
import os

ip_list = ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]

for ip in ip_list:
    response = os.popen(f"ping {ip}").read()
    if "Received = 4" in response:
        print(f"UP {ip} Ping Successful")
    else:
        print(f"DOWN {ip} Ping unsuccessful")
```

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Probably the problem is in path, use full path of ping: ```/usr/bin/ping```

Comment: @TelinovDmitri - The location is OS-dependent.  Given the error message, it appears to be Windoze; which is not located at the stated path.

Comment: @S3DEV yes, you are right - given the error message, but on Linux/Mac the output of ```which ping``` could be used :)

Comment: Even on Windows the error definitely points to a PATH problem - add ```%SystemRoot%\system32``` to the PATH

Comment: Cannot reproduce - `os.popen(f"ping {ip}").read()` works for me: windows, executed from a random directories. `ping` location is in my path environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on windows

```
import os

ip_list = ["127.0.0.1"]
for ip in ip_list:
    response = os.popen(f"C:\Windows\System32\ping {ip}").read()
    if "Received = 4" in response:
        print(f"UP {ip} Ping Successful")
    else:
        print(f"DOWN {ip} Ping unsuccessful")
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the computer cannot find an executable program for `ping`, so it cannot execute the `ping` command.

You can fix the problem by adding the `ping` executable directory to your computer's environment variables.

1. <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `sysdm.cpl` and press enter

   [image]
2. Select **Environment Variables** at the bottom right

   [image]
3. Double-click **path** (*you can choose to add variables for the **user** or for the entire **system***)

   [image]
4. Choose **New** and enter `C:\Windows\system32`

   [image]
5. OK, then reopen vscode

*Sorry my system language is Chinese. For more information on creating environment variables you can check this [link](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).*

[image]