# How can I run python -m http.server in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am just starting to learn Python and I'm using VS Code.

First of all, how does one open a python terminal without running a python script? "Terminal > New Terminal" opens a new Powershell terminal. The plus in the terminal has no option for opening a Python terminal.

The bigger problem: I am learning Python using VS Code and need to use the python webserver but receive "python not found" error. Python is installed and I've added the Python extension in VS Code. I have a workspace and I've created my python environment (venv). I know the python terminal command to run a webserver is python -m http.server 8000. Yet when I run the command I receive "Python not found." I've done this before so clearly there's something else I'm not understanding.

Awhile back I created a workspace in VS Code for something else and created a python environment (venv). Somehow back then I was able to run python -m http.server 8000 from python terminal to start a webserver. To try and solve my current problem, I went back to that workspace, and sure enough I can still run the command from the python terminal that opened with it there. Confused why one terminal works and another doesn't, I opened a new python terminal (the only way I know how, running a python script by clicking the "run python file" play button). A new python terminal opens and there's my little hello world script. I try to run python -m http.server 8000 from there and I get the same "python not found" message as in my other workspace.

What am I missing? How do I have one terminal that can run the command and another that can't? And how do I open python terminals without having to run a python script?

VS Code installed. Python installed. Python Extension installed to VS Code. Opened workspace folder, created python environment (pointed it my python.exe). Ran a "hello world" python script to get a python terminal. Ran python -m http.server 8000 from the terminal and get "Python not found."

Comment: to open a Python REPL terminal use the command **Python: Start REPL**, do not run `python -m http.server 8000` in a Python REPL but an OS terminal that has your venv enabled

Comment: what is the prompt you see in the different terminals: if it is `>>>` you have a Python REPL, any thing else with `(venv) some/dir/path` is an OS terminal

Comment: I guess they're both OS terminals then. Any idea why one terminal would know about python and the other not? I just don't remember how I got this working in the past. The terminal that opened with my older workspace also restored it's history on its own.

Comment: I saw a post on another question that had the command py --version. Curious if that would work for me, I tried it and it worked. So I tried py -m http.server 8000 and it worked. One terminal recognizes python the other terminal recognizes py. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

> how does one open a python terminal without running a python script?

Type `python` directly in the terminal or use the `Python: Start REPL` command.

[image]

As for your terminal not recognizing `python`, you can add the python path to the environment variable. How to do that can be found in [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73382360/19133920).